# JSON with angular and node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular

Hi guys I am very new to node JS and angular. I am currently working on some handling JSON file with Angular and Node JS but unfortunately, I faced a problem at the moment. I am trying to return all of the JSON elements(key&value) once it is called. For example, some JSON element has key named 'role' and some of them are not so I want to retrieve all of them first then deal with that... please help me

JSON file

```
{"name":"Manager"},
{"name":"Brad","role":"chef"},
{"name":"Edward","role":"chef"},
{"name":"Kim","role":"waiter"},
{"name":"Park"}
```

**check.js**

```
module.exports = function(app,fs) {
    app.get('/check', (req, res) => {

        var worker_with_role = [];

        fs.readFile('user.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            worker_with_role = JSON.parse(data);
            res.send(worker_with_role);
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

**ajax**

```
function list() {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location + '/check',
        type: 'get',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

I am using ajax.. so I want to receive the data

Comment: What you want to do is unclear. Do you want to return a json from your node app only containing the elements containing the `role` property?

Comment: I want to return every elements that is stored in JSON file..

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do this: `worker_with_role = JSON.parse(data);`

`JSON.parse` converts stringified JSON into a `JSON Object`. And you can't send JSON Objects to the response. It should be `stringified/serialized`.

```
module.exports = function(app, fs) {
  app.get('/check', (req, res) => {
    var worker_with_role = [];
    fs.readFile('user.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

On the client when you receive this, you can then parse it there to convert it into a JSON Object. Although Angular's `HttpClient` does that automatically for you.

### Update:

If you're using Angular, please don't use `jQuery` to make AJAX Calls. That just beats the whole purpose of using Angular in the first place.

Use [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http#setup) instead.

Comment: You might mention the need to parse it client side

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks for answer but man i am little confused all i want to do is returning every json data that is currently stored in `user.json` to the client.. is that the quick and simple way to do ??? sorry to ask you silly question..

Comment: Yeah that's the method that I've told you about in the answer.